# Как лучше перевести "peer"?

Tags: выбор-слов, переводы

Я перевожу BitTorrent-клиент. В нём используется замечтельный термин "[peer](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer)", который обозначает участника обмена информацией.
В других BitTorrent-клиентах это слово переведено как "пир", что может быть непонятно нетехническим пользователям.

Как лучше перевести "peer"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В контексте торрента это слово по смыслу точно соответствует "участнику" (торрента), при этом участники делятся на *сидеров* и *личеров* (эти слова имеют новые для русского языка значения, и их употребеление оправдано). Поскольку введение слова "пир" ничего не меняет в данном контексте, терминологически оно столь же бесполезно, как "юзер", да и звучит оно странно в применении к человеку. Я бы ограничился простым и ясным "**участник**" - это и будет точным переводом слова *peer* применительно к контексту торрента.

Comment: ...или даже соучастник :D

Answer (score 1):

Peer - это участник (равный среди равных, никакой специальной роли не выполняющий). Но это не обязательно живой человек (user), это может быть бот (устройство, программа). Рекомендую переводить как "участник" с периодической заменой на подходящий по контексту синоним (пользователь/устройство/узел...), или уточнением.

Answer (score 0):

Из русских слов точнее всего **обменивающийся**, правда получается длинно. Участника равноправного партнерства еще можно назвать **товарищ**, но слово прочно ассоциируется с СССР, хотя в настоящее время это может даже плюс.

Comment: Это по жизни минус) Но вообще да, если есть, где размахнуться в UI, то участник, а если нет, то пир (сам видел это слово на русскоязычных трекерах — пиры и сиды).

Comment: Я тоже видел на трекерах "пиры" и "сиды". Просто, имхо, эти слова не очень понятны нетехнической аудитории.

Comment: Главное чтоб не попутали и не написали "сиры" и, гм...